# Change header text of columns in a GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a GridView which i programmatically bind using c# code.
The problem is, the columns get their header texts directly from Database, which can look odd when presented on websites. So basically, i would like to modify the column header text, but programmatically.
i have already tried the following,

```
testGV.Columns[0].HeaderText = "Date";
```

and

```
this.testGV.Columns[0].HeaderText = "Date";
```

does not seem to give me correct result.

Comment: Could you elaborate on "does not help"? Do you get an error? How are you binding data to the grid?

Comment: why not change the column name using AS keyword while retrieving data from SQL?

Comment: basically im using,
SqlDataAdapter
DataSet

---------
adapter.Fill(ds);

testGV.DataSource = ds;
testGV.DataBind();
---------

Comment: change it in the query or the stored procedure you use to get data

Comment: If you're AllowSorting the gridview, use the Sorted() event to handle the suggestions below, otherwise putting it in RowDataBound() will not work

Answer (score 55, accepted):

You should do that in GridView's [`RowDataBound`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowdatabound.aspx) event which is triggered for every `GridViewRow` **after** it was databound.

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header)
    {
        e.Row.Cells[0].Text = "Date";
    }
}
```

or you can set [`AutogenerateColumns`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.autogeneratecolumns.aspx) to `false` and add the columns declaratively on aspx:

```
<asp:gridview id="GridView1" 
  onrowdatabound="GridView1_RowDataBound"
  autogeneratecolumns="False"
  emptydatatext="No data available." 
   runat="server">
    <Columns>
         <asp:BoundField DataField="DateField" HeaderText="Date" 
            SortExpression="DateField" />
    </Columns>
</asp:gridview>
```

Comment: is changing the column name using As keyword while retrieving from SQL a better option? am not sure if its recommended

Comment: @TimSchmelter thank you i just wanted to make sure its a good way of doing it

Comment: was wondering, how do i call the function protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)

Comment: Thanks. Helped me.

Comment: GridViewRowEventArgs I get the error this name type of namespace is not knowing!!! how do I resolve it

Comment: no actually Im using asp.net in SharePoint environment

Answer (score 19):

I Think this Works:

```
 testGV.HeaderRow.Cells[0].Text="Date"
```

Comment: Short and sweet. Good answer!

Comment: best answer off all!

Comment: Which GridView event is that best placed in?

Comment: It works for me in the DataBound event, but I don't know if that's the best place for it...it's slow...maybe that event gets called a gazillion times...

Comment: PreRender seems faster.

Answer (score 4):

You can do it with gridview's datarow bound event. try the following sample of code:

```
protected void grv_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header)
{
e.Row.Cells[0].Text = "TiTle";
}
}
```

For more details about the row databound event study [Thsi....](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowdatabound.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Better to find cells from gridview instead of static/fix index so it will not generate any problem whenever you will add/remove any columns on gridview.

ASPX:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound" >
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Date" DataField="CreatedDate" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

CS:

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < e.Row.Cells.Count; i++)
        {
            if (string.Compare(e.Row.Cells[i].Text, "Date", true) == 0)
            {
                e.Row.Cells[i].Text = "Created Date";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

On your asp.net page add the gridview

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" onrowdatabound="GridView1_RowDataBound" >
</asp:GridView>
```

Create a method protected void method in your c# class called GridView1_RowDataBound

as

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header)
    {
        e.Row.Cells[0].Text = "HeaderText";
    }
}
```

Everything should be working fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void grdDis_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            #region Dynamically Show gridView header From data base
            getAllheaderName();/*To get all Allowences master headerName*/

            TextBox txt_Days = (TextBox)grdDis.HeaderRow.FindControl("txtDays");
            txt_Days.Text = hidMonthsDays.Value;
            #endregion
        }
    }
```