# Linq using variable as column name in select new statement

Tags: linq, variables, select

I have a LINQ query and as you can see I am trying to use variables as column names.

```
string first = "someColumnName1";
string sec = "someColumnName2";
string third = "someColumnName3";

var data = (from i in ctx.PlanskaKalkulacijas
            where i.PKid.Value == id
            select new { first = i.NP1, sec = i.NP2, third = i.NP3}
           ).OrderByDescending(m => m.Id)
            .ToList();
```

this code produce column names in gridview as first, sec and third but I need someColumnName1, someColumnName2, someColumnName3.

Any help ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either rename columns in the gridview after you insert data or name properties of the anonymous type you create properly.

```
var data = (from i in ctx.PlanskaKalkulacijas 
            where i.PKid.Value == id 
            select new 
            { 
                someColumnName1 = i.NP1, 
                someColumnName2 = i.NP2, 
                someColumnName3 = i.NP3
            }).OrderByDescending(m => m.Id)
              .ToList();
```

If you don't know values at compile time, just rename it. To do that, follow [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13013241/change-header-text-of-columns-in-a-gridview) here on SO.

Comment: I suspect that the question author does not actually know the column names at compile time. @zire - can you clarify if you know the column names at compile time?

Comment: Yes RB,   column names I am getting from db and those names will be different.

Comment: @zire Ok, than just rename headers.

Comment: Thanks again Ondrej this works:protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header)
    {
        e.Row.Cells[0].Text = "Date";
    }
}